# Where can I find spanish subtitles for Dragon Ball legally?

Tags: dragon-ball, resources

I want to learn Spanish by watching Dragon Ball (original, not Z, not GT) with Spanish dub *and* sub. I found all episodes with Spanish dub, but I cannot find the subbed version of Dragon Ball Z in Subbed (Spanish).

Does anyone know where, if, I would be able to watch them legally in Spanish Subbed if possible?

Comment: Welcome to the Anime & Manga SE! I've voted to close this as off-topic because requesting sources of illegal (or copyrighted) material is generally considered not fit for this site for legal reasons. I would suggest you consider looking into official DVDs that might have Spanish subtitles, or trying either [our site chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-manga-chat) or a more discussion-based anime forum.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote - instead of closing it I would suggest editing it in the first place if it is possible. (which it is). I think we should always assume they mean legally (which is why I usually try to edit the question + title to point out legally rather than close the question).

Comment: hey, nice trying to dodge the close vote by adding "legally" to the question, but no cake.

Comment: To the fellow SE folks that are trying to save the questions, fight the good fight friends. Save them if you can!